# Convert Facenet .npz trained model to tensorflow-lite (tflite) format

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have used combination of MTCNN (for face detection) and Facenet model is trained on different faces and have generated weights (face embedding) into .npz file. I have used Keras API to load model and train and use it for inference for further face recognition. This whole setup is working fine.

Now, I want to use the same weights for Face Recognition in Android app using Firebase AutoML custom model implementation which supports only tensorflow-lite models. So I want to convert the Facenet trained weights (face embedding in '.npz' file format) into tensorflow-lite (.tflite) model.

But I am not able to find any solution for it there are options to convert Facenet frozen model '.pb' file to convert into tflite. Click [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/facenet-on-mobile-cb6aebe38505) for details.

Please help if you have any idea about this conversion.

Thanks